# Unable to sort in rich:scrollabledatatable

Tags: spring, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to create a table out of **rich:scrollableDataTable**. I am able to see data on the table by i am not able to sort it from the browser. Neither i am receiving any error. Can anyone please suggest me what am i missing?? I am new in DataTables.

The facelet's code and beans code is as follows:

- JSF 1.2
- RichFaces 3.3.GA

  ```
  <rich:scrollableDataTable  width="1000px" id="slowJobPerTable"
                         value="#{bean.model}"
                         sortOrder="#{bean.order}"
                         selection="#{bean.selection}"
                         var="jobList"                               
                         sortMode="multiple"
                         style="border:0px solid black;">

  <rich:column  width="130px" id="slowJobDate" style="padding:0px;">
      <f:facet name="header" class="data-table-header3" parent="slowJobDate">
          <h:outputText value="Date" style="color:black;"/>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{jobList.startRunDate}" style="align:center;"/>
  </rich:column>

  <rich:column  width="350px" style="padding:0px;" id="slowJobDesc" >
      <f:facet name="header" class="data-table-header3" parent="slowJobDesc">
          <h:outputText value="Job Description" style="align:center;color:black;" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{jobList.jobDescription}"/>
  </rich:column>

  <rich:column width="130px" style="padding:0px;" id="slowJobType" >
      <f:facet name="header" class="data-table-header3" parent="slowJobType">
          <h:outputText  value="Job Type" style="align:center;color:black;" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{jobList.jobType}"/>
  </rich:column>

  <rich:column styleClass="right-align" width="130px" style="padding:0px;" id="slowJobDuration" >
      <f:facet name="header" class="data-table-header3" parent="slowJobDuration">
          <h:outputText value="Duration" style="align:center;color:black;" />
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{jobList.timeTaken}"/>
  </rich:column>

  <rich:column styleClass="right-align" width="130px" style="padding:0px;" id="slowJobRecords" >
      <f:facet name="header" class="data-table-header3" parent="slowJobRecords">
          <h:outputText value="Records" style="align:center;color:black;" /> 
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{jobList.records}"/>
  </rich:column>

  <rich:column styleClass="right-align" width="130px" style="padding:0px;" id="slowJobRate">
      <f:facet name="header" class="data-table-header3" parent="slowJobRate">
          <h:outputText value="Rate" style="align:center;color:black;" /> 
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{jobList.rate}"/>
  </rich:column>
  ```

My Bean Class is as follows:

```
@Controller("bean")
public class BatchThroughputBean implements Serializable {

private SortOrder order = new SortOrder();
private SimpleSelection selection = new SimpleSelection();

public BatchThroughputBean() {
        SortField[] fields = {
            new SortField("startRunDate", false),
            new SortField("jobDescription", false),
            new SortField("jobType", true),
            new SortField("timeTaken", false),
            new SortField("records", false),
            new SortField("rate", false)
        };
        order.setFields(fields);
    }

    public SortOrder getOrder() {
    return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(SortOrder order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public SimpleSelection getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelection(SimpleSelection selection) {
        this.selection = selection;
    }
}
```

Comment: The @sortMode should be just "multi" but the table should be sortable anyway (the attribute defaults to "single" for any other value).

Comment: @Makhiel It is not working even in just 'multi'.

Comment: Try making the sortField names the same as column ids, that said "not working" is not very descriptive.

Comment: I did not received any error that is why less descriptive.
Here when i received an id then It is giving an error like
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'slowJobDate' not found on type com.model